# Вывод контента в зависимости от активного radio

Tags: javascript

```css
    label {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 10px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    label > input {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .circle::before {
      content: '';
      border: 2px solid #dfe4eb;
      border-radius: 50px;
      background: white;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 18px;
      height: 18px;
      position: relative;
      top: 5px;
      right: 5px;
    }
    
    .circle::after {
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 50px;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      background: #dfe4eb;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 10px;
      z-index: 0;
    }
    
    input[type="radio"]:checked + .circle,
    .circle:hover {
      color: black;
    }
    
    input[type="radio"]:checked + .circle::before {
      content: '';
      border-radius: 50px;
      background: #0093D8;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      border: 5px solid white;
      box-shadow: 0 0 2px #0093D8;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .circle:hover::before {
      content: '';
      border-radius: 50px;
      background: red;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      border: 5px solid white;
      box-shadow: 0 0 2px red;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
    }
```

```html
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rb" checked>
      <span class="circle">Физические лица</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rb">
      <span class="circle">Юридические лица</span>
    </label>
    <div>Контент для физических лиц, виден по умолчанию!</div>
    <div>А здесь контент для юридических лиц, виден, если выбраны юр.лица! Соответственно, блок контента для физ. лиц скрывается.</div>
```

Comment: А где ваш код, как вы пробовали решить эту ситуацию? Что именно непонятно?

Comment: Не знаю как решить на JS используя атрибут checked.

Comment: у вас есть доступ к атрибуту...

Comment: Тогда лучше всего в вопросе написать весь ваш код, кроме тех моментов где вы не знаете как сделать. Эти моменты мы вам поможем решить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  if(!e.target.hasAttribute('data-type-legal')) return;
  a2.hidden = !a2.hidden
  a1.hidden = !a1.hidden
});
   if (document.documentElement.hidden === undefined) {
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "hidden", {
  set: function(value) {
    this.setAttribute('hidden', value);
  },
  get: function() {
    return this.getAttribute('hidden');
  }
});
  }
```

```css
label {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 10px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    label > input {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .circle::before {
      content: '';
      border: 2px solid #dfe4eb;
      border-radius: 50px;
      background: white;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 18px;
      height: 18px;
      position: relative;
      top: 5px;
      right: 5px;
    }
    
    .circle::after {
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 50px;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      background: #dfe4eb;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 10px;
      z-index: 0;
    }
    
    input[type="radio"]:checked + .circle,
    .circle:hover {
      color: black;
    }
    
    input[type="radio"]:checked + .circle::before {
      content: '';
      border-radius: 50px;
      background: #0093D8;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      border: 5px solid white;
      box-shadow: 0 0 2px #0093D8;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .circle:hover::before {
      content: '';
      border-radius: 50px;
      background: red;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      border: 5px solid white;
      box-shadow: 0 0 2px red;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    [hidden] { display: none }
```

```html
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rb" checked data-type-legal>
      <span class="circle">Физические лица</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rb" data-type-legal>
      <span class="circle">Юридические лица</span>
    </label>
    <div id="a1">Контент для физических лиц, виден по умолчанию!</div>
    <div id="a2" hidden>А здесь контент для юридических лиц, виден, если выбраны юр.лица! Соответственно, блок контента для физ. лиц скрывается.</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем так, контент у юр.лиц должен быть скрыт, если активны физ.лица.

Comment: @ikar добавить только атрибут hidden и логику a2.hidden=!a2.hidden...

Comment: hidden это интересно, но поддержка только начиная с IE11

Comment: @ikar надо же,кому то нужен IE11-...Вообще это надо указывать задавая вопрос,переделываю последний раз

Comment: Про `hidden` не знал, спасибо!